# What is the correct way of writing two MSc degrees on a business card?

Tags: masters, titles

If someone would have obtained two MSc degrees, how do you put that on a business card?

I myself have two MSc degrees from a Dutch university. The degrees are Computer Science which gives me the Dutch title *ir*, and Science Communication which gives the Dutch title *drs*. Both degrees are internationally an MSc (as indicated on my diplomas). I know that in Holland I can use the following:

- drs. ir. John Doe

Since the Dutch titles are confusing in international use (especially the *drs* part), I would like to use the international format on my business card. For **one** MSc I know that it is written internationally like this:

- John Doe, MSc

However, how is the international format for two MSc degrees?

Comment: What context are you using these business cards in? If you're in academia, there's probably no point putting your degrees on it, and depending on your industry this might be true too.

Comment: I am currently working as a PhD researcher in a German defense-related company. Since Germans like their titles, I thought it might be good to include both my MSc titles on the business card (they provide an entire line for them in their format)

Comment: That makes sense, but I think Germans are kind of unique in their interest in degrees? So I think a business card which is "complete" from a German perspective might look like you are trying too hard for people from most other business cultures.

Comment: John Doe, (MSc)^2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

> John Doe, MSc (Comp. Sci.), MSc (Sci. Comm.)

? (Then again, this *could* look pretentious. Proceed with caution.)

Unfortunately, the relevant [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nominal_letters#Etiquette_for_deciding_which_higher_educational_qualifications_may_be_listed_post-nominally) is not highly informative, and anyway it is flagged as "citations required" and specific to the UK:

> Where two different postgraduate qualifications with the same name
>   have been obtained (for example two different postgraduate MAs from
>   King's College London and University of Sussex), this can be indicated
>   by using one degree postnominal, and the abbreviations of the two
>   awarding bodies in parentheses, sometimes joined by the Latin "et" (or
>   with an ampersand), e.g. "Jane Smith MA (KCL et Sussex)", and not
>   "Jane Smith MA MA". However, when qualifications with the same name
>   have been gained through different routes (for example an MA from
>   Oxford University converted from a Bachelor of Arts, and a studied and
>   examined postgraduate degree from King's College London these are
>   listed separately with the institution only listed after the
>   non-examined qualification (e.g. "Jane Smith MA(Oxf) MA", and not
>   "Jane Smith MA (Oxf et KCL)").

Comment: *John Doe, MSc (Comp. Sci.), MSc (Sci. Comm.)* This comes across as trying too hard to me. I think if you **must** put anything after your name, a single MSc is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing business with countries where the number of titles is important (e.g., Germany), I would suggest to write only a single MSc on your business cards (and in your email signature).

You can highlight the two titles in your CV.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am doing business in Germany, in an industry where they also like ranks.